# ASP.NET DI Exception with Generic Repository and multiple Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I am confused about DI and these dependency containers.
Can't inject my dbcontext and services into my application.

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Server.Logic.Registration.IRegistrationService' for service type 'Server.Logic.Registration.IRegistrationService'.

Stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.Populate() in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll:token 0x600007a+0xea
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory..ctor(IEnumerable`1 descriptors) in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll:token 0x6000079+0x3e
```

Multiple guides on the internet are about single IRepository and a single table.
While I my Repository is generic.

IRepository

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    void Create(TEntity item);
    TEntity FindById(int id);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get();
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    void Remove(TEntity item);
    void Update(TEntity item);
}
```

GenericRepository

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable where TEntity : class
{
    public DbContext _context { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet { get; set; }
 
    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
 
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get()
    {
        return _dbSet.AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }
     
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToList();
    }
    public TEntity FindById(int id)
    {
        return _dbSet.Find(id);
    }
 
    public void Create(TEntity item)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Update(TEntity item)
    {
        _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Remove(TEntity item)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_context != null)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
                _context = null;
            }
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

In many points of my code, I have to use multiple entites of these Generic Repository.
Because I have around 9 tables. And sometimes I have to take info from more than one table.

Here is my service and it's interface, which is realizing my logic.

```
 public interface IRegistrationService
    {
        public JsonResult GetAll();
        public JsonResult GetById(int id);
    }
```

And my Registration Service

```
 public class RegistrationService : IRegistrationService
    {
        public IRegistrationService _sender;
        private GenericRepository<RegistrationCountByMonth> _repoWithDates { get; set; }
        private  GenericRepository<RegistrationCountByDevicesAndMonth> _repoWithDataAndDevices { get; set; }
        private  GenericRepository<DeviceType> _deviceTypes { get; set; }


        public RegistrationService(GenericRepository<RegistrationCountByMonth> dates, 
            GenericRepository<RegistrationCountByDevicesAndMonth> devices,
            GenericRepository<DeviceType> deviceTypes, IRegistrationService sender)
        {
            _repoWithDates = dates;
            _repoWithDataAndDevices = devices;
            _deviceTypes = deviceTypes;
            _sender = sender;
        }
        
        public JsonResult GetAll()
        {
            var crudeInfoByMonth = _repoWithDates.Get();
            List<CleanByMonth> infoListToReturn = new List<CleanByMonth>();
            foreach (var crudeInfo in crudeInfoByMonth)
            {
                if (crudeInfo.Month == DateTime.Today.Month)
                {
                    CleanByMonth item = new CleanByMonth
                    {
                        year = crudeInfo.Year, month = crudeInfo.Month, registeredUsers = crudeInfo.NumberOfUsers
                    };
                    infoListToReturn.Add(item);
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult(infoListToReturn);
        }

        public JsonResult GetById(int id)
        {
            int year = MySimpleMath.TakeNDigits(id, 4);
            int month = int.Parse((id % 100).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
            var registrationByDeviceAndMonth = _repoWithDataAndDevices.Get();
            
            CleanWithBoth returnInfo = new CleanWithBoth();
            returnInfo.year = year;
            returnInfo.month = (byte)month;
            returnInfo.registeredUsers = 0;
            List<Provision> specificData = new List<Provision>();

            var devices = _deviceTypes.Get();
            foreach (var dataSet in registrationByDeviceAndMonth.Where(x => x.Year == year && x.Month == month))
            {
                Provision info = new Provision();
                info.type = devices.First(x => x.DeviceId == dataSet.DeviceType.Value).DeviceName;
                info.value = dataSet.NumberOfUsers;
                specificData.Add(info);
                if (dataSet.NumberOfUsers != null)
                {
                    returnInfo.registeredUsers += dataSet.NumberOfUsers.Value;
                }
            }
            returnInfo.registeredDevices = specificData;
            return new JsonResult(returnInfo);
        }
    }
```

Here is how I am using the asp.net default dependency injection.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IRegistrationService>();

            services.AddTransient<IRegistrationService, RegistrationService>();

            services.AddTransient<RegistrationService>();
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(
                    options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:LocalDB"));
            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

I can't understand where is my error. Should I maybe somewhere use "new" ?

Please, can you point me to a solution. I really want to understand DI.
But my projects are not that simple as all of those guides..

Maybe I should move myself to Ninject, instead of the default asp.net DI tools ?

Comment: Not sure about this one but containers often require specific registrations rather than open. Means, instead of AddScoped( IFoo<>, Foo<> ) you'd have to register AddScoped( IFoo<X>, Foo<X> ) and same for other entity types.

Comment: So I should do this for every table in my model ? 

I can make the registration service with an extension method and it will be easy. 
I just don't quite understand this logic. If it is like you say. Then.. if we will have an enterprise project. With thousands of tables... it it really that necessary ?

Comment: Some containers have high level methods to automate this. Also, just try it for a single table to check if it works. Leave complaints for later.

Comment: The error is using the "generic repository" *anti*pattern in the first place. Your `Update` can easily execute 43 INSERTS and 64 DELETEs, because a DbContext is *already* a Unit-of-Work and caches all changes. The changes are committed only when `SaveChanges` is called. You won't solve the problem by changing DI implementations. Read [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) to understand how dangerous the current code is.

Comment: You didn't post the full exception text that would explain what the actual problem is in an inner exception, what class couldn't be instantiated. I'd bet it's `IRegistrationService ` - which of all the registration types do you want to inject? Even after removing that parameter, by making the "service" transient, the "repositories" scoped and calling `SaveChanges` on every call, it's impossible to roll back changes without using an actual database transaction through a TransactionScope

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos

https://hastebin.com/opizegidoy.apache

Thanks for the article. Will read it asap

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the following lines:

services.AddTransient();
services.AddTransient();